# % occurrence as result in a Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this data set

```
Date Hour Indicator
5/10/2018 9 F
5/10/2018 9 F
5/10/2018 9 F
5/10/2018 9 NF
```

and looking to get this result set and need this result set as columns(No multiindex) as i can plot these

```
Date        Hour  Indicator %Indicator
5/10/2018 9          F           75
5/10/2018 9         NF          25
```

Comment: You've selected python as your language which suggests you have a reason. Do you have an example or attempt at the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby` with `len`:

```
res = df.groupby(['Date', 'Hour', 'Indicator'])\
        .apply(len).div(len(df.index))\
        .reset_index()

print(res)

        Date  Hour Indicator     0
0  5/10/2018     9         F  0.75
1  5/10/2018     9        NF  0.25
```

Comment: thanks for this. How would i calculate the percentage when grouped by hour

5/10/2018 9 F
5/10/2018 9 F
5/10/2018 9 F
5/10/2018 9 NF
5/10/2018 10 F
5/10/2018 10 F
5/10/2018 10 F
5/10/2018 10 NF

Desired output

        Date  Hour Indicator     0
0  5/10/2018     9         F  0.75
1  5/10/2018     9        NF  0.25
2  5/10/2018     10         F  0.75
3  5/10/2018     10       NF  0.25

Comment: @SuhasR, I would make sure you understand the solution I provided; happy to answer anything about syntax that's unclear. Understanding the logic will let you perform a wide range of calculations as required. If you remain stuck, feel free to ask a separate question. If this answer helped, feel free to accept (green tick on left).